# Modifying a custom form on submit

Tags: 10

I have a custom module with a custom form, Drupal 10, and when the form is submitted I want to either 1. add some markup to the submitted page or 2. change a value on the form. I have failed on the former, so I am trying the latter.

Here's my code, without the chaffe:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state): array {
    $form['plate'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('Plate'),
    ];

    $form['actions'] = [
        '#type' => 'action',
        'submit' => [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => $this->t('Search'),
        ],      
    ];
}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state): void {
    $this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('The form has changed'));
    $form_state->setValue('plate', 'Changed Value');
    $form_state->plate = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('Plate wjiijowqoiwefewiofjewfio'),
        '#value' => 'Changed Value',
        '#default_value' => 'Changed Value',
    ];
    $form_state->plate['#value'] = "Changed Value";
    $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

Can you see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The form elements should be manipulated in the build method. You can use the current state of the form there too.

To override the user input, you can't use `setValue` on the form state. The form system is built to maintain user input on rebuild, so you have to manipulate that directly:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state): void {
  $this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('The form has changed'));

  $input = $form_state->getUserInput();
  $input['plate'] = 'Changed Value';
  $form_state->setUserInput($input);

  $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

Then in the build method you can change things based on whether the form has been submitted:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state): array {
  $submitted = $form_state->isSubmitted();

  $form['plate'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $submitted ? $this->t('Plate submitted') : $this->t('Plate'),
  ];

  if ($submitted) {
    $form['html'] = [
      '#markup' => '<p>Something</p>',
    ];
  }

  $form['actions'] = [
    '#type' => 'action',
    'submit' => [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Search'),
    ],      
  ];

  return $form;
}
```

As an aside, there's almost never a need to set `#value` on a form element directly - it will stop that element from accepting any new user input. You can use `#default_value` to set the initial value, and then the form state methods to manipulate it during a form lifecycle.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you, Clive. I didn't know about those methods, and that's going to make form manipulation all the more easy! Awesome.

Now just to work out how to get data from the form back to the controller!