Webforms AJAX. How to change the value of a textfield (f_text) when the user select a value in a select field (f_select) using Drupal 10 api ajax
Following the instructions in Ajax forms I try to apply this to a webform. I built a webform with two fields. And in my_module.module, I add a hook_form_alter() with the following code:
$form['elements']['f_select']['#title'] = 'Select a color';
$form['elements']['f_select']['#ajax'] = [
  'callback' => 'promptCallback',
  'wrapper' => 'color',
];
$form['elements']['f_text']['#prefix'] = '<div id="color">';
$form['elements']['f_text']['#sufix'] = '</div>';
$value = $form_state->getValue('f_select');
\Drupal::logger('iac_test_form')->error('<pre><code> ' . 'Select value:  ' . print_r($form_state->getValue('f_select'), true) . '<pre><code> ' );
if ($value){
 $form['elements']['f_text']['#value'] = $value;
}

And the callback function
function promptCallback(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){ 
return $form['elements']['f_text'];
}

After select a value, the form goes through the hook again and the value selected is in the $form_state->getValues('f_select'); but the textfield does not update.
If I try this in a custom form all works properly, like in the Simplest AJAX example of the example module.
Drupal 10.3.1 webform 6.2.3

Any reason you're using $form_state->getValues('f_select') (plural) to get the value, but $form_state->getValue('f_select') (single) to debug it? Also, never set #value directly, as this will overwrite user input. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/319663/modifying-a-custom-form-on-submit/319664#319664 for some more info and examples

You are right, there is an error, it is getValue... but that does not solve the problem. I want to get the value of f_select to change the value of f_text, when f_select change and before submitt the webform.
